# VScode not able to run Jupyter Notebook in venv in other folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I have the following problem:

I want to use an virtual environment created with venv with a Jupiter Notebook in VScode but I'm not able to add it. The environment is in a different Folder than the Code-workspace.
I have another workspace saved in the same folder as the environment and in this workspace it works without a problem. I'm also able to load the environment to execute normal python scrips, but I always have to search it in the explorer.

I've tried *Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel*, but it is not listed there. If I click at S*elect Another kernel...* -> *Python environments* it is also not listed. (I already loaded it for a normal python script)
I have also tried to ad the path under *Settings*-> *Python: Venv Folders*.